# How to run tests in random order with robotframework maven plugin?

Tags: integration-testing, pom.xml, maven-plugin, robotframework

I am trying to run Robotframework testcases from eclipse with Robotframework-maven plugin. Can anyone tell me the configuration of POM.xml to run the testcases according to my given order instead of alphabetical order? For example, I have the following tags in the corresponding test suites:

```
TestSuit1--->
             Testcase1.robot  --  >MyTestcase1 [Tags]  a
             Testcase2.robot  ---  >MyTestcase2 [Tags]  b
             Testcase3.robot  -- - > MyTestcase3 [Tags]  c
```

I want to executes the above test cases random order. If I write in pom.xml

```
<includes_cli>b,a,c</includes_cli>
```

It executes the tests according to alphabetical order instead of my given order. Can anyone have a solution for that?

Br,
Dew

Comment: The order is not related to maven. Robotframework's ordering rules are described [in the user guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#execution-order). In general, if your tests need to be run in a particular order, rewrite them to not need to be run in a particular order. It's a very bad idea, since people might run them individually, or distribute them over multiple machines, or the rules might change...

Answer (score 4):

You can use --randomize option to execute the test cases in random order as below:

Case 1:

```
 robot --randomize tests <Testcase1.robot>
```

tests:   Test cases inside each test suite will be executed in random order

Case 2:

```
  robot --randomize suites <path/to/Testsuite>
```

suites:  All test suites will be executed in a random order, but test cases inside suites will run in the order they are defined

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. But how to configure maven pom.xml  to implement this solution?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the latest version of the maven plugin has a randomize option:

http://robotframework.org/MavenPlugin/run-mojo.html#randomize

options are:

```
<randomize>all</randomize>
<randomize>suite</randomize>
<randomize>test</randomize>
```

with the default being no randomization.

Looks like the same options as for the `--randomize` command line argument for the robot command:
http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#randomizing-execution-order